Docusign envelopesApi.ListDocuments failing with a valid header and settings
I have referred to all of the documentation and several posts here and I think my situation is unique.
I am getting this error:

PARTNER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED
The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled. An Integrator key was not specified

As the docs suggest I have double checked and the integration key, account id and end point(s) are all correct.  This issue is occurring in production with an integration that has been in use for a few years with the EnvelopesApi to create envelopes with no issues.
The Envelopes.ListDocuments call works if I point everything at demo just fine.
The prod integration has its own private key...
I am using DocusignClient.RequestJWTUserToken and the token returned is valid, and it DOES work to get account info with this call:
DocusignClient.GetUserInfo() <-- this works!
But, when I call
EnvelopesApi.ListDocuemnts(the_account_id_from GetUserInfo, 
                           a_known_good_envelopeId); 

it fails with that error I mentioned above.
The docs say to make sure the accountid, integration id, endpoint(s) - restapi one and auth end point are correct and they are.  How else could I create envelopes and get user info?
Scopes for the call are
 var scopes = new List<string>
 {
     "signature",
     "impersonation",
 };

Can anyone help?
*Edit
restapi endpoint is: https://na2.docusign.net/restapi
Matches what I see in Apps & Keys in docusign
Auth endpoint: account.docusign.com
**Edit 2:  Auth appears to be working , maybe...
Now I am getting "File or directory not found" 404 on each envelopeid I try to call with ListDocuments.  The envelopeId's do exist and can be viewed on docusign's site.
```
AuthUtil auth = new AuthUtil(_keyVaultConfiguration);
OAuth.OAuthToken token = auth.GetTokenFromJwt();
Account account = auth.GetAccountInfo(token);

DocuSignClient docuSignClient = new DocuSignClient(account.BaseUri);
docuSignClient.Configuration.DefaultHeader.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token.access_token);

EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(docuSignClient);

// known good envelopeId
EnvelopeDocumentsResult results = envelopesApi.ListDocuments(account.AccountId, eml.TEnvelopeId);

foreach (EnvelopeDocument doc in results.EnvelopeDocuments)...


Code throws the 404 before the foreach is reached.

What would cause this?

  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/rETVzgxk.png


Check that you're calling the production end points for both obtaining the access token (via jwt flow) and calling the eSign API.
The sdk defaults to demo. You need to set the prod base path that you get back from the user info call.
The prod oauth address is account.docusign.com

Thank you, you set me on the right path!   What worked for me is to use follow these docs HereNote: This placeholder base path is used only for the ApiClient RequestJWTUserToken, RequestJWTApplicationToken, and GetUserInfo methods. Once you make these calls, you should be able to get the correct base path and use it to make all other API calls.  So I did it exactly like that used the constants to get the token and userinfo, then a new DocusignCliwent using the baserUri in the Account.
